# Why does my Python program fail when called from Java?

Tags: java, python, python-2.7, sympy

In essence I have this program:

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol
x = Symbol('x')
print solve(x**2 - 1, x)
```

And I call this from [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29) using this code:

```
public static BufferedReader runFile(Class<?> c, String py, List<String> args) {
    String cmd = c.getResource(py).getPath();
    cmd=cmd.split(py)[0];
    cmd=cmd.substring(0,cmd.length()-1);
    args.add(0, py);
    args.add(0, "python");
    final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args);
    new ProcessBuilder();
    pb.directory(new File(cmd));
    pb.redirectError();
    try {
        System.out.println(pb.directory().getPath());
        for(String s:pb.command()){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        Process p=pb.start();
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
    }
    catch (final IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

When I run the Python program from a terminal everything works as intended, with nothing in the error stream, and it prints [-1,1]. But if I run it from the program, I get this in the error stream:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solve.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sympy.solvers import solve
ImportError: No module named sympy.solvers
```

Comment: Are you using virtualenv or anything like that?

Comment: @jpmc26 not sure what that is, but no. I am using raw java 7 and python 2.7. Along with sympy.

Comment: Did you install sympy globally? How, if so?

Comment: @jpmc26 I used pip install sympy.

Comment: What version of Python, by the way?

Comment: @jpmc26 said in an earlier comment: 2.7

Comment: Sorry. I am blind sometimes.

Comment: Can you run `where python` (for Windows) or `which -a python` (for Linux/Mac) from the directory that it works in?

Comment: @jpmc26 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python but the file being run is the same as the one run from java...

Comment: The script is the same, but I was trying to find out if you might have multiple versions of the interpreter, which wouldn't be able to find each others' packages. What if you specify the full interpreter path on the command line and in Java? ...Also, just to double check, these are both on the same machine; right?

Comment: @jpmc26 yep same machine. How could I supply the full path?

Comment: Paste `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python` on the command line (instead of just typing `python`) and in your code above (where you currently have `"python"`).

Comment: @jpmc26 AWESOME that works great. If you make an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since specifying the full path of Python fixes your problem, you most likely have multiple installations of Python on your system. Rather than `PYTHONPATH` being different, I suspect it is actually `PATH` that is different. As a result, your command line uses the Python interpreter you intend, while Java uses another one.

To determine where this alternate install is, `which -a python` may be useful, but if not, examine `PATH` from inside your Java code and see if you can find Python in one of those directories.

Regardless, if you really need to specify the full Python path in Java, you should make this a configuration option. It will probably be different on different machines. Storing it in a file seems most prudent.

Answer (score 1):

Your `PYTHONPATH` (or less likely your working directory) is different when running from your Java context.

You can

```
 import sys
 print sys.path
```

which may help you to ensure the path is the same for both.

Telling us more about how your environment is set up will help to get more specific answers.

eg. Maybe the Java is running via a web server or something?

---

Here are couple of ways to fix the path problem:

Make sure the directory containing `sympy` is in your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable

If you're really desperate, append the correct directory to sys.path

```
import sys
sys.append("/some/dir/with/sympy")
from sympy.solvers import solve
...
```

Comment: I don't think `PYTHONPATH` is the problem. Python adds the global `site-packages` to `sys.path` by itself, whether you have `PYTHONPATH` set or not. Unless there's some way to override that behavior? (I'm sure virtualenv does something fun, but that's not in play.) Checking `sys.path` wouldn't hurt, though.

Comment: @jpmc26, it's even possible the OP is running an entirely different instance of the Python interpreter for all I know. There are really only a few reasons why this module might not be found, but it's going to be really hard to guess without more input from the poster.

Comment: Ok the PYTHONPATH is different. Is there a way I can workaround the module not being present.

Comment: You can probably make it use the other Python's site-packages using `PYTHONPATH`, but it can lead to issues, especially if you are also using compiled modules, or if the Python version is different (even by a minor point). Setting `PATH` to the right thing is a much better idea.